# Slow image loading using spritespin.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Im trying to animate 360 degree spin on a page using lot of images (110) with the spritespin bundle, which means that they are all loaded so that means the page take some time to be viewable. I tried preloading only one frame but then when I spin the picture around some frames dont load correctly (i get white spaces instead), especially on the last frame (so most likely the last frame still did not load).

So this is my spritespin config:

```
<script>

var frames = SpriteSpin.sourceArray('/images/RcH_png_000{frame}.jpg', { 
    frame: [1, 110]
});

$(".spritespin").spritespin({
  // path to the source images.
  source: frames,
  //width   : 480,  // width in pixels of the window/frame
  //height  : 327,  // height in pixels of the window/frame
  responsive: true,
  animate: false,
  preloadCount:1,
  plugins: [
      '360',  // display plugin
      'drag', // interaction plugin
    ]
});
</script>
```

You can also check how the website is slowly loading here:
https://dry-cove-88007.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

```
    var frames = SpriteSpin.sourceArray('/images/RcH_png_000{frame}.jpg', { 
            frame: [1, 110]
        });  
//add img 
       let imgLoading = $('<span class="loadersprite"><img src="/images/loading.gif"></span>');
       imgLoading.insertAfter('.spritespin');
```

and then in the oncomplete method

```
  $(".spritespin").spritespin({
  source: frames,
  //width   : 480,  // width in pixels of the window/frame
  //height  : 327,  // height in pixels of the window/frame
  responsive: true,
  animate: false,
  preloadCount:1,
  plugins: [
      '360',  // display plugin
      'drag', // interaction plugin
    ],
     onComplete:function(){         
        imgLoading.hide();
        }
});
```